# Sitecore, jQuery ajax, and WebMethod returns the page itself

Tags: jquery, ajax, sitecore, webmethod

I am trying to use jQuery ajax to call a WebMethod on an aspx page that I have in my application. I am following this article: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

I noticed that when I try to make the ajax call, it is giving me the page itself (myPage.aspx) and not the results of my WebMethod. At this point, I am basically using the code straight from the article above. The javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
$("#Result").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myPage.aspx/GetDate",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            $("#Result").text(msg.d);
        }
    });
});
});
```

The myPage.aspx code-behind for the WebMethod is:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetDate()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

The strange thing is that I had it working on a separate test page, but when I tried to integrate it into the actual page where I want to use it, it doesn't. I couldn't find anything that resolved my issue when searching the site and web.

I'm running Sitecore 6.5 and .NET Framework version 4.0. Can anyone help or provide insight?

Comment: Why dont you include error function like this  error: function (xhr, status, error) { var msg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                   alert(msg.Message);} and see if it is throwing any errors or else use firebug to check the request and resposne

Comment: @user1042031 I previously looked at the Response headers and it was returning text/html which was the HTML of the page itself. I am not really sure why this is happening though.

Answer (score 0):

I am only familiar with PHP but usually you have to json_encode() your array before returning back.  So for example in php

```
$TestArray['d'] = "All My HTML";
echo json_encode($TestArray);

//Then in Jquery

$("#Result").html(msg.d);
```

and make sure there is a div with the id of Result...

Answer (score 0):

Typically, that happens when the request is either not a POST or doesn't have the `application/json` Content-Type set.

I'm not familiar with Sitecore, but others seem to have had trouble with it interfering with page methods: [How to use jquery ajax and webmethod with sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560111/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-and-webmethod-with-sitecore)

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that Sitecore's URL rewriter will handle the request and ignore the `/GetDate` part of your url.

Therefore you must add your aspx to the `<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" />` setting.

Comment: I put in a support ticket with Sitecore and they responded that this is caused with an issue in the RewriteModule. They did say that it is not reproducible in 6.5-Update 4, so upgrading Sitecore may do the trick, but I am unable to do so right now. I did try adding my page to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting, but that did not help.

Thanks for the response!

Comment: This is not a option because you'll lose the Sitecore context